# Conversion of opencv C++ code to Python opencv code

Tags: c++, python, opencv

```
cvAbsDiff(imaggray, imaggray1, imaggray2);
CvScalar sumDiff = cvSum (imaggray2);
ar1[0] =   (long int) sumDiff.val[0] + (long int) sumDiff.val[1] + (long int) sumDiff.val[2];
```

This is the c++ code where `ar1` is a `long int` array. The absolute difference of the images `imaggray` and `imaggray1` is stored in `imaggray2`.

In python:

```
cv.AbsDiff(imaggray, imaggray1, imaggray2)
```

I am having trouble in converting the second and third line to python.

How should I do that ?

Comment: `cv` module is going to be removed from OpenCV. So please migrate to `cv2` module.

Answer (score 0):

As Abid commented, I would use cv2 rather than cv module. Since cv2 is based on c++ interface, you can develop scripts with fewer lines of code assuming you can do OOP. Another advantage of using cv2 is that python statement is mostly analogous to its c++ statement

```
drawing2 = cv2.absdiff(drawing,drawing0)
sc = cv2.sumElems(drawing2)
ar = sc[0] + sc[1] + sc[2]
```

[More details are here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html)